# É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Quando devo fazer essa gravação direto no banco?

Quais as situações?

Eu sei que posso gravar no banco o caminho da imagem.

Comment: O MS SQL Server oferece uma solução que conta com o melhor dos dois mundos (FILESTREAM): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx Ah se todos os bancos tivessem um recurso assim! (de preferência padronizado).

Comment: Eu estou terminando de desenvolver um sistema de repositorio de noticias e imagens e estou me deparando com essa mesma dúvida. Só para você ter uma idéia tem mais de 20 anos de noticias com 1TB só de fotos. Dessa forma imagina se precisar voltar um backup de banco com mais de um TB de tamanho. Minha sugestão é se for poucas imagens que nao passem de 100mega bytes no total você pode usar o banco para simplificar. Mas se form maior do que isso utilize o file system. Se tiver na nuvem use o S3 do amazon ou serviço correspondente nas outras nuvens.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Além do custo ser mais alto como mencionado, deve-se levar em conta vários fatores:

- **Volume de dados**: para um baixo volume de dados pode não haver problema. Por outro lado, para armazenamento de grande massa de dados o banco de dados é praticamente inviável. Pergunte ao Facebook ou ao Google se eles usariam banco. O Facebook, por exemplo, usa um sistema de arquivos personalizado para tornar o acesso mais rápido ainda e diminuir a o *overhead* por arquivo exigido pelos sistemas de arquivos tradicionais.
- **Clusterização**: uma vantagem do banco de dados é no caso do seu sistema rodar em vários servidores, todos terão acesso uniforme aos arquivos. Porém, usar uma unidade na rede para armazenar os arquivos.
- **Disponibilidade**: seu sistema vai ter muitos acessos? Isso pode sobrecarregar um banco de dados tradicional. Por outro lado, seu servidor HTTP pode usar as rotinas de acesso de baixo nível ao sistema de arquivos para enviar o stream de dados ao cliente.
- **Escalabilidade**: se a demanda de volume ou disponibilidade aumentarem, será possível adicionar mais capacidade ao sistema? É muito mais fácil dividir arquivos entre servidores diferentes do que distribuir registros de uma tabela em mais servidores.
- **Flexibilidade**: fazer cópias de segurança, mover arquivos de um servidor para outro, fazer algum processamento nos arquivos armazenados, tudo isso fica mais fácil se os arquivos estiverem num diretório. Se você faz o deploy em ambiente de cliente, os arquivos no disco **não** inviabilizam você de receber cópias do banco de dados para testes. Tente pedir para o seu cliente enviar terabytes de dados para você analisar se der algum problema no banco.
- **Overhead de leitura e gravação**: o custo computacional para gravar e ler dados do banco de dados é maior do que para ler e gravar diretamente em um arquivo.

Existem várias estratégias para escalar um sistema tanto em termos de disponibilidade quanto em volume. Basicamente essas estratégias consistem em distribui-los em vários vários servidores e redirecionar o usuário para cada um deles conforme algum critério. Os detalhes variam de implementação, tais como: estratégia de atualização dos dados, redundância, critérios de distribuição, etc.

Uma das grandes dificuldades em gerenciar arquivos fora do BD é que temos agora duas fontes de dados distintas e que precisam estar sempre em sincronia.

Do ponto de vista de segurança, efetivamente há pouca diferença. Se um *hacker* pode comprometer um servidor, ele poderá ler tanto os arquivos gravados em disco do seu sistema quanto os arquivos do sistema de banco de dados. Se essa questão for crítica, uma alternativa é armazenar os dados criptografados.

Porém, sempre que fiz a análise do melhor tipo de solução, o uso do sistema de arquivos sempre esteve em grande vantagem.

Comment: +1 Essa resposta resumiu tudo muito bem... e ainda adicionou alguns pontos. Deixei esse comentário pois sei que organizar uma resposta assim é algo trabalhoso, e só dar um upvote não me bastou. Parabéns! =D

Answer (score 25):

Não é errado... a maior parte dos desenvolvedores evita fazer isso, pois geralmente o **custo de espaço em banco de dados costuma ser muito maior que o custo de storage**.

Então o ideal é que você use o storage para armazenar grandes massas de dados, e o banco de dados relacional para armazenar dados estruturados.

Mas imagine que você não faça isso, e que vá sempre usar um banco de dados local... nesse caso, você pode armazenar no banco de dados, que não vai fazer diferença. Mas ainda assim, eu acho que seria mais fácil gravar na forma de arquivo... usando a própria linguagem que estiver usando. Essa é geralmente uma operação bem mais fácil do que salvar no banco.

Com essa estratégia de gravar no storage e fazer referência usando um caminho, você terá de gerenciar a integridade manualmente... o que também pode se mostrar bem difícil:

- apagar os arquivos quando o registro associado deixar de existir
- garantir que o arquivo não seja apagado, enquanto existir um registro apontando para ele
- garantir a atomicidade da operação de criar um registro juntamente com o arquivo

Comment: também sou a favor de armazenar apenas o nome do arquivo no database, assim também facilita manutenção das fotos, muito mais fácil visualizar as fotos pelo Explorer do sistema operacional do que pelo Banco de dados.

Answer (score 18):

Você pode gravar bytes de imagem diretamente no banco de dados quando suas preocupações não incluem:

- Espaço no banco (devido ao alto custo)
- Velocidade de acesso

Contudo, gravar o caminho da imagem no banco pode gerar certas dificuldades quanto ao gerenciamento de backups, restaurações e permissões de acesso.

**Em suma**, a melhor prática depende das características de sua aplicação e de suas necessidades operacionais, levando em conta o banco utilizado, o sistema de arquivos e o fluxo de requisição dos dados.

Comment: Caso queira dar uma olhada, existe uma [pesquisa](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) na Microsoft Research que compara o armazenamento de grandes objetos (BLOBs) no SQL Server 2005 e nos arquivos de sistema de tipo NTFS.

Answer (score 16):

Além do que todos mencionaram aqui, é interessante gravar na base de dados quando você precisa por medidas de segurança **garantir a integridade do registro de dados com a imagem/arquivo** bem como **diminuir a superfície de risco no acesso às imagens num sistema de arquivo**.

Por exemplo: Quando um registro na base jamais possa existir sem que haja uma imagem associada. Por exemplo foto 3x4 de uma identidade ou uma radiografia e seu laudo, etc...

Essa decisão deverá ser calcada principalmente na **análise não-funcional** da sua solução.

Answer (score 7):

Pode gravar as imagens no banco de dados sem problema. Aqui no serviço temos um banco de 1,5T, com 95% disso sendo de imagens. Mas é necessário verificar o motivo desta decisão. No meu caso, a segurança é prioridade. 
Faça um estudo sobre segurança, rede, quantidade de acesso, gerenciador de arquivos para o seu propósito. Por experiência própria, se for possível, grave apenas o caminho como disse e armazene no disco. Dependendo do tamanho do seu banco, estas imagens serão muito piores de gerenciar backups e replicações do que no disco.

Answer (score 4):

Já fiz um sistema que sincronizava imagem com os respectivos dados no banco, gravando o filename da imagem num campo varchar do banco e salvando a imagem com o código do registro no banco para relacionar.

É perfeitamente possível fazer a sincronia de arquivo de imagem com banco de dados, porém isso depende muito mais do conhecimento do programador do que da tecnologia aplicada - não é um negócio pronto e até hoje ainda não fiquei sabendo de algum projeto pronto para isso. Todos os sistemas de banco de imagens que conheci não utiliza banco para armazenar as imagens e sim storage.

Uma coisa que torna o trabalho difícil mesmo é a criação de um mecanismo próprio para indexação das imagens, importante para classificar e pesquisar as imagens de forma bem eficiente e flexível (se precisar disso, claro). Mas acho que no geral essa parte é feita através do próprio banco de dados (uma tabela já pode servir como indexador). Eu tropecei bastante neste parte e descobri que aqui no Brasil muito dificilmente encontramos informação suficiente para produzir esse tipo de sistema. É necessário entender até mesmo o sistema de arquivos adequado para se criar um arquivo de indexação, pois haverá um limite no tamanho do arquivo...