# Melhor forma se armazenar imagens em base de dados

Tags: android, mysql

Tenho uma aplicativo android que utiliza um banco de dados mysql,  para armazenar informações do perfil dos meus usuários, mas gostaria de saber a melhor forma de armazenar as fotos da cada usuário, pois pensei em fazer upload da imgs quando ele tirasse e salvasse apenas o url, porém essa operação de upload e download de imgs toda hora que eu for abrir o perfil de um usuário não é muito custosa? Se eu for fazer um listview com as fotos de várias pessoas se eu baixar todas estou gastando muito certo? Se essa for a solução ideal, acredito que de alguma forma devo diminuir o tamanho da imagem antes de upar,  pois tem celulares com resolução alta que salvam as imgs com mais de megas.

Comment: Veja esta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/7261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a library  [Universal Image Loader for Android](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) ela trabalha exatamente nesses questões de carregar url de imagens em listview ou gridview. Você ainda consegue fazer tratamento para renderizar o tamanho das imagens.

Exemplo:

```
// DON'T COPY THIS CODE TO YOUR PROJECT! This is just example of ALL options using.
// See the sample project how to use ImageLoader correctly.
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
        .taskExecutor(...)
        .taskExecutorForCachedImages(...)
        .threadPoolSize(3) // default
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
        .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
        .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
        .diskCacheFileCount(100)
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
        .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder()) // default
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
        .writeDebugLogs()
        .build();
```

Simple

```
String imageUri = "http://site.com/image.png"; // from Web
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)


// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito bom, então a melhor opção seria mesmo eu fazer o upload das imgs e salvar apenas url, outra coisa que faltou é como eu poderia renderizar o tamanho da imagem antes de subir ela na hospedagem.

Comment: No servidor tu deixa ela full (se você precisa de qualidade na imagem), daí, você trata ela com essa biblioteca já no código. tipo... `ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(50, 50);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136183/universal-image-loader-did-not-apply-the-displayimageoptions-in-loadimage