# Inserção de documentos pdf e doc

Tags: php, file-upload

Estou a fazer um Backoffice no qual tenho que fazer a inserção de documentos de `.doc` e `.pdf` mas não sei como fazer, alguém pode ajudar?

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="envia_pdf.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label> Selecione o arquivo PDF: </label>
<input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="envia" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

E este código a baixo é o código do ficheiro de PHP:

```
<?php 

// Verifica se o campo PDF está vazio
if ($_FILES['pdf']['name'] != "") {

// Caso queira mudar o nome do arquivo basta descomentar a linha abaixo e fazer a modificação
//$_FILES['pdf']['name'] = "nome_do_arquivo.pdf";

// Move o arquivo para uma pasta
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],"documentos/".$_FILES['pdf']['name']);

// $pdf_path é a variável que guarda o endereço em que o PDF foi salvo (para adicionar na base de dados)
$pdf_path = "../documentos/".$_FILES['pdf']['name'];

} else {
// Caso seja falso, retornará o erro
 echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo";
}

?>
```

O problema é que quando carrego no botão para o documento ser enviado, ele não me dá erro nenhum mas só que o documento não é enviado para a base de dados nem para a pasta que está referida no código.

É esse o problema deste código.

Comment: Essa tarefa pode ser divididas em sub atividades como, criar o form, receber/fazer o upload e gravar no banco. Decida se vai gravar o pdf no banco como um blob(ou equivalente) ou apenas o caminho dele, para saber algumas das vantagens desvantagens veja: [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/91)

Comment: O form já tenho feito, mas so que nao sei fazer o receber/fazer o upload e gravar no banco e na pasta onde irão estar todos os documentos

Comment: Que bom, então edite a pergunta e coloque o código do form(selecione o código e use o botão `{ }` para formata-lo.

Comment: ai está o meu form, e tenho agora também um ficheiro de php no qual tem algum codigo de inserção penso

Comment: Quando for fazer perguntas sempre coloque o código fonte caso seja muito extenso a deixe apenas parte relevante, mensagens de erros, não esqueça de descrever o problema um forma de fazer isso é dizer o que você quer fazer e qual o resultado que o sistema deve retornar e evite termos como `não funciona` prefira detalhar ex: a tela ficou em branco e não inserir o registro, isso ajuda muito quem vai responder. Se tentou algo também coloque na pergunta, ex: tentei aboragem A e obtive o erro 000, segui esse link e deu o erro 1111. Agora só falta descrever o problema :).

Comment: Você tem permissão de escrita nessa pasta? Para forçar a exibição dos erros, adicione no inicio do seu php: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Não tenho permissão de escrita pois esse não me aparece nenhuma mensagem quando faço submit

Comment: Adicione uma barra antes de documentos: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],"/documentos/".$_FILES['pdf']['name']);` Ou defina o caminho completo da pasta dos uploads

Answer (score 3):

No HTML pode colocar assim:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="envia_pdf.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="infraFieldset">
        <legend class="infraLegend">Enviar Arquivos</legend>
        <label id="lblArquivo" for="txtArquivo" class="infraLabelObrigatorio">Documento:</label>
        <input type="file" id="txtArquivo" name="txtArquivo" value="" />
        <button type="submit" accesskey="S" name="sbmSalvar" class="infraButton"><span class="infraTeclaAtalho">E</span>nviar</button>
</form>
```

No PHP:

```
$pathToSave = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].
"/pasta onde quer salvar/";

/*Checa se a pasta existe - caso negativo ele cria*/
if (!file_exists($pathToSave)) {
    mkdir($pathToSave);
}

if ($_FILES) { // Verificando se existe o envio de arquivos.

    if ($_FILES['txtArquivo']) { // Verifica se o campo não está vazio.
        $dir = $pathToSave; // Diretório que vai receber o arquivo.
        $tmpName = $_FILES['txtArquivo']['tmp_name']; // Recebe o arquivo temporário.

        $name = $_FILES['txtArquivo']['name']; // Recebe o nome do arquivo.
        preg_match_all('/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $name, $extensao);
        if (!in_array(strtolower(current(end($extensao))), array('.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.xls', '.xlms'))) {
            echo('Permitido apenas arquivos doc,xls,pdf e txt.');
            header('Location: '.suapagina.php);
            die;
        }

        // move_uploaded_file( $arqTemporário, $nomeDoArquivo )
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $dir.$name)) { // move_uploaded_file irá realizar o envio do arquivo.        
            echo('Arquivo adicionado com sucesso.');
        } else {
            echo('Erro ao adicionar arquivo.');
        }    
    }  
}
```

Comment: onde diz "/pasta onde quer salvar/"

meto o caminho todo ou so assim : ../documentos

Comment: ai depende da sua estrutura. provavelmente vai colocar apenas o /documentos sem o ..

Comment: Já tenho outro código para a inserção de PDF, mas agora existe um problema que é o seguinte :o código envia o ficheiro para a pasta referida mas não envia o nome do ficheiro para a base de dados
o que teria que fazer para o ficheiro ir para a pasta referida e o nome do ficheiro ir para a base de dados

Comment: Percebeu qual é o meu problema?