# Como fazer um formulário que aceite upload de foto e salve no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Criei um banco de dados chamado `Form` e tabela com as seguintes informações

```
contatos (id int A.I, nome varchar(30), idade int(2), foto(blob)
```

Fiz aquele formulário padrão:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="CadastroAlunos" type="text" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">

  Nome: <input type="text" name="NomeAluno"></br>
  Idade: <input type="text" name="IdadeAluno"></br>
  Foto: <input type="file" name="image" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="envia" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPLOAD.PHP**

```
<?php
     include_once 'conexao.php';

     $nome = $_POST['NomeAluno'];

     $idade = $_POST['IdadeAluno'];

     $foto = $_FILES['image'];

     move_uploaded_file ( string $foto , string $novoDestino );

     $sql = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, idade, foto) values ('$nome', '$idade', $novoDestino");
?>
```

Como faço para gravar a foto junto com as de mais informações do formulário?

Comment: Use `$_FILES` para manipular o arquivo, `$_POST` para informações do form e [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) para transferiro o arquivo para o servidor.

Comment: Entendi o que disse, só que estou com problema para implementar. Havia visto alguns códigos antes, só que a pessoa fazia upload da foto para uma pasta no computador. Quero que vá pro banco de dados. Vou editar minha pergunta e adicionar o php que fiz. Se puder dar uma olhada

Comment: Você precisa pegar o conteúdo do arquivo com [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) isso retornara uma 'string' ai basta gravar no banco. Pode fazer um teste e imprimir o retorno de `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Eu recomendo que salve a imagem em uma pasta e em seu banco você grave o caminho para o arquivo, salvar o proprio arquivo no banco de dados não é uma das melhores praticas pois o seu banco pode ficar sobrecarregado e começar a apresentar lentidão.

Comment: Relacionado: [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/91)

Comment: @rray irei ver isso agora mesmo.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly então, quanto a isso nem preciso me preocupar tanto, porque esse projeto é acadêmico, irei fazer upload de algumas imagens só. Mas obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o tipo **BLOB** para a coluna `foto` que receberá o conteúdo do `input type="file"`.

Seu código PHP para inserção no banco ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = $_POST['NomeAluno'];
$idade = $_POST['IdadeAluno'];

$imagem = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
$tamanho = $_FILES['image']['size']; 
//$tipo = $_FILES['image']['type']; 
//$nomeImagem = $_FILES['image']['name'];

if ( $imagem != "none" ) { 
    $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb"); 
    $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho); 
    $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo); 
    fclose($fp); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, idade, foto) values ('$nome', '$idade', '$conteudo')";

    mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die("Algo deu errado ao inserir o registro. Tente novamente."); 

    echo 'Registro inserido com sucesso!'; 

    //header('Location: index.php'); 

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0) 
        print "A imagem foi salva na base de dados."; 
    else 
        print "Não foi possível salvar a imagem na base de dados."; 

} else 
    print "Não foi possível carregar a imagem.";
?>
```

Comment: Tentei implementar desta forma que enviou mas da erro nesta parte : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.png'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\up\upload.php on line 11`. Porque será deste erro?

Comment: fiz uma edição no código, eu havia trocado o comando `$nomeFinal= time()'.jpg';` de posição. Verifique se o problema persiste, caso ainda ocorra tente fazer o upload de uma imagem .jpg.

Comment: Alterei e tentei fazer o upload de uma imagem .jpg mas o erro persiste nesta linha ainda `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.jpg'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\up\upload.php on line 9`

Comment: novamente alterado, o erro era na mesma  linha. Faltou um '.'

Comment: Agora passou dessa parte e parou em uma que parece ser mais complexa: `Warning: fopen(1443794568.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\up\upload.php on line 15` e também

 `Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\up\upload.php on line 15`

Comment: tentei outra abordagem, editei novamente a resposta.

Comment: Há um exemplo mais completo na documentação do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Fiz pequenas edições no que me enviou agora e deu certo. Agradeço a paciência. Muito obrigado! :D @feresjorge

Comment: Edite a publicação com o código funcionando, pode servir para outra pessoa. Peço desculpas por não ter testado o código antes, não foi possível.

Answer (score 2):

Acho mais recomendável salvar o caminho da imagem no banco, eu faria dessa forma:

```
<?php
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = $_POST['NomeAluno'];

$idade = $_POST['IdadeAluno'];

$foto = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$tamanho_permitido = 1024000; //1 MB
$pasta = 'uploads';

if (!empty($foto)){
    $file = getimagesize($foto);

    //TESTA O TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO
    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > $tamanho_permitido){
        echo "erro - arquivo muito grande";
        exit();
    }

    //TESTA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO
    if(!preg_match('/^image\/(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i', $file['mime'])){
        echo "erro - extensão não permitida";
        exit();
    }

    //CAPTURA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $extensao = str_ireplace("/", "", strchr($file['mime'], "/"));

    //MONTA O CAMINHO DO NOVO DESTINO
    $novoDestino = "{$pasta}/foto_arquivo_".uniqid('', true) . '.' . $extensao;  
    move_uploaded_file ($foto , $novoDestino );

} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, idade, foto) values ('$nome', '$idade', $novoDestino";

echo $sql;
?>
```