# Duvida sobre armazenamento de arquivos em servidor

Tags: banco-de-dados, cliente-servidor

Qual a melhor forma para armazenamentos de arquivos em um servidor, como binário em banco de dados ou salva-lo em diretórios. Existe alguma diferença entre custo de processamento em uma aplicação web?

Comment: Oi, funke, pedir uma resposta baseado em apenas duas frases não é exatamente uma boa pergunta... Que servidor usa? Já tentou binário ou diretório? Porquê acha que vai haver custo? Etc... Se sabe Inglês, a leitura disto é tipo essencial: [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/%c3%89-errado-gravar-byte-de-imagens-no-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo depende da solução que pretende implementar e quais recursos você já possui.
Armazenar na Base de Dados é uma boa ideia, não tem grande impacto na performance (ao contrario do que muita gente pensa - pelo menos no SQL Server), desde que no SELECT incluam-se o menor número de vezes possiveis o campo em que contem o ficheiro. Mas tem o problema da limitação da Base de Dados em si. Ou seja, dependendo da licença de SQL Server que tiver, esta pode ou não ser uma boa ideia.

Caso opte por gravar fora da Base de Dados, também deve pensar em como vai gerir os endereços. Pois, "qualquer" utilizador com acesso a pasta, pode perfeitamente mudar o nome do ficheiro, colocar numa outra pasta, etc, e tudo isto sem actualizar o mapeamento na Base de Dados.

Ainda tem a solução da Cloud, que ai a história também é outra.