# Opções de bancos de dados multimidia

Tags: banco-de-dados, multimedia

Sei que existe o tipo blob nos bancos de dados mais comuns do mercado para salvar arquivos, mas existe algum outro banco de dados desenvolvido especificamente para trabalhar com arquivos multimídia?

ps: Não tenho nenhum propósito para uma aplicação em especifico, apenas que o pai google sempre retorna os bancos de dados comuns.

Comment: Seu interesse é simplesmente em armazenar arquivos multimídia, ou em fazer operações mais sofisticadas com eles? O [artigo da Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_database) fala um pouco do assunto, mas não lista muitas opções não, e eu desconheço bancos desses tipos. Normalmente quando é só pra armazenar, é melhor fazer em arquivos mesmo (em geral, [melhor até que usar blob](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/215)) Mas se um uso específico é desejado - por exemplo, buscar dentro de uma imagem por um padrão ou forma específico - aí realmente é necessário um BD próprio

Comment: Era mais curiosidade do que qualquer outra coisa.