# Armazenamento de arquivos, em banco de dados ou disco?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, armazenamento

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema intranet, com um módulo de armazenamento de arquivo (exclusivamente PDF).

O que vocês me indicam em relação ao local de armazenamento, salvo em disco no servidor ou em banco de dados?

Lembrando que é uma intranet. O servidor fica na mesma rede, e o banco de dados é ORACLE. Ambos "backupeados".

Se possível argumentem a escolha (Em questão de desempenho, segurança dos dados, etc)

Comment: Veja se as respostas aqui resolvem sua dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente não é uma boa ideia armazenar arquivos binários grandes no banco de dados, é melhor guardar a referência do local deles dado o overhead, velocidade de acesso, número de acessos, tamanho do arquivo e afins.

**Porque armazenar no Banco de Dados:**

- As propriedades ACID são garantidas, inclusive fazer *Rollback* de um
  *update*, o que é muito complicado quando as informações são armazenadas fora do Banco de dados.
- O arquivo sempre tem um "Pai"
- Backup do banco já garante que os binários serão salvos

**Porque salvar no Disco:**

- O tamanho de arquivos binários varia para cada banco de dados quando
  se é usado FileStream, dependendo do tamanho do PDF terás que fazer
  uma pequena mágica =[
- A gerência de arquivos no banco de dados é relativamente mais
  complexa do que a gerência no disco e conforme o número de dados no
  banco é necessário um conhecimento maior sobre classificação de
  arquivos, índices e afins.
- Portabilidade de arquivos, pois o formato PDF é "universal", o que
  não pode ser dito para o FileStream do DB
- Dependendo do banco escolhido a conexão para upload e download de
  arquivos pode dar uma pequena dor de cabeça para alguns problemas já
  conhecidos de cada banco
- Caso seja feito um upload para a Web, tu tens que implementar um
  handler do FileStream e isso toma muito mais tempo e conhecimento
  técnico além de ser um fator de falha
- Você não pode usar a cloud para uma possível escalabilidade do
  sistema

Recomendo criar o seguinte esquema:

```
____________________________________________
| ID | TIME | QUERY | PDF_NAME | PDF_FILE  |
|----|------|-------|----------|-----------|
```

Importante notar que caso prefira usar um DB é muito mais recomendável usar FileStream do que um Blob por questões performáticas.
[Essa leitura](https://sqltales.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/varbinary-vs-filestream-and-other-blob-issues-3/) vai te ajudar a entender FileStream, Blob e Varbinary

Essa é a [FONTE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database), mas me alterei alguns conceitos para o seu propósito =]

**Edit**: Oracle usa BFile como tipo e não FileStream

Comment: Obrigado Matheus, tenho mesmo uma tendência a salvar em disco. Já implementei algo parecido uma vez, mas sem saber muito o porque. Sua resposta esclareceu bastante algumas dúvidas que tinha.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

O desempenho do software é igual em ambos os casos segundo [oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/loading-documents-and-other-file-data-into-the-oracle-database)  no texto também mostra sobre as diversas formas de apresentar ou carregar do banco arquivos.
 Depende muito mais de quanto desempenho a sua maquina tem para processar os dados.
 Eu gosto mais de colocar  em arquivo separado e manter no banco de dados só o link do arquivo.