# Qual a melhor forma de armazenar arquivos em uma webapplication?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, codeigniter-3, multiple-file-upload

Pretendo armazenar arquivos do tipo docx, pdf, entre outros para acessar na minha aplicação web, onde o banco de dados é o MySql, e o framework usado é o Codeigniter. Alguém poderia me explicar qual maneira seria melhor de implementar e armazenar os arquivos, tendo em vista tratar de sistema jurídico, onde cada arquivo upado deverá estar relacionado a um número de processo?

Comment: [Armazenamento de arquivos, em banco de dados ou disco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215110/5878)

Answer (score 1):

No CI um estou usando local, e salvo no banco junto a um registro o nome do arquivo ou local e depois chamo o arquivo onde necessito...

Exemplo de banco

id, nome, perfil, idade, ...

na coluna pefil fica a imagem de perfil exemplo 1.png caso id dele seja 1 caso eu salve o local fica pasta/1.png e faço um código em php para salvar o arquivo em uma pasta.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, teria algum video ensinando como fazer isso que você explicou no CI?

Comment: outro dúvida é como bloquear o acesso via browser para usuários não logados?

Comment: Na pasta que for armazenar os arquivos coloca um htaccess com deneis para ninguém acessar.

Comment: Veja se esse tópico te ajuda: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/upload-de-arquivos-com-php