# Como armazenar imagem no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho um app com cadastro de produtos que tem 3 EditText e 2 imageView. Estou tentando salvar esses valores no SQLite mas tem algo de errado pois não dá erro mas também não salva, segue o código.

```
   mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                mSQLiteHelper.insertData(

                        mEdtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        mEdtAge. getText().toString().trim(),
                        mEdtPhone.getText().toString().trim(),
                        imageViewToByte( mImageView),
                        codeViewToByte( ivQRCode)

                );
                Toast.makeText( Produtos.this, "Salvo com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                mEdtName.setText( "" );
                mEdtAge.setText( "" );
                mEdtPhone.setText( "" );
                mImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.addphoto );
                ivQRCode.setImageResource( R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } ); 

  public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap1.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream );
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

public static byte[] codeViewToByte(ImageView code) {
    Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) code.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap2.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream2 );
    byte[] byteArray2 = stream2.toByteArray();
    return byteArray2;
}
```

metodo insertData

```
  public void insertData(String name, String age, String phone, byte[] image, byte[] code ){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement( sql );
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString( 1,name );
    statement.bindString( 2,age  );
    statement.bindString( 3,phone);
    statement.bindBlob  ( 4,image);
    statement.bindBlob  ( 5,code );

    statement.executeInsert();
}
```

Comment: Só uma observação: A boa prática é salvar os arquivos em uma pasta específica e armazenar apenas o caminho deles no banco de dados. Pesquise melhor sobre este assunto caso queira saber mais. Mas claro, tudo parte da necessidade também.

Comment: [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/%C3%89-errado-gravar-byte-de-imagens-no-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Concordo com o @RBZ, você tratar byte de imagens é muito chato, você fazendo o upload da imagem e salvando o caminho é muito mais prático

Comment: Obrigado.  Mas as imagens que estou usando são imagens geradas, a primeira com a camera do celular e a outra uma imagem QRCode,, não tenho o caminho delas

Comment: @DanielRaibolt aí o que faz com as imagens é você que define, se vai para o banco, se armazena no dispositivo, em memória interna ou externa, etc. Mas, foi só uma dica mesmo para saber que não se usa dessa forma.

Comment: Reverti sua edição, pois você está sim armazenando imagem no banco. O novo título que havia colocado, ficou estranho.

Comment: Pessoal, gostaria que se alguém puder me ajudar vendo em meu projeto o que pode estar causando o erro,  sou iniciante e estou com dificuldades pra encontrar o problema.