# Exibir foto cadastrada no banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Quero exibir uma foto cadastrada no banco de dados que foi cadastrado em um atributo do type blob. Porem não quero exibir a foto através de um link onde você click e abrir a foto, na pagina é encaminhado o id onde chama a função para selecionar e mostrar os dados e a foto. A função a baixo:

```
public function selecionarPetFoto($id,$pdo){
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Foto_pet FROM pet WHERE Cod_pet=:cdp LIMIT 1");
            $sql->BindValue(':cdp',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
```

> OBS: Já está tudo cadastrado e os dados já está exibido corretamente, só a foto que não to conseguindo exibir.
>   Lembrando não é errado, depende das características de sua aplicação e de suas necessidades operacionais.

Comment: A melhor maneira mais eficiente de armazenar e recuperar fotos é no sistema de arquivos deixando apenas o caminho registrado no banco de dados. Isso porque blob e campos de tamanho variável inflacionam e desalinham a estrutura de armazenamento das linhas, comprometendo o desempenho das consultas.

Comment: Use ['base64_encode()'](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php) no `blob`. Se a foto for um `jpeg` e `$row` for uma linha retornada pela consulta: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Foto_pet'] ).'"/>';`

Comment: @AugustoVasques E se eu quiser apagar a foto com a seleção do id e usando o delete, irar apagar só caminho da imagem ou irar apagar a imagem na pasta do servidor onde foi armazenada?

Comment: Só o caminho. Apague a imagem  com `unlink()`.

Comment: deu certo usando o base64_encode(), vou estudar direito pra me saber qual é mais viavel

Comment: Como ninguém se habilitou a dar uma resposta, estou a apresentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que `Foto_pet` seja um JPEG e `$row` uma linha retornada pela consulta:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Foto_pet'] ).'"/>';
```

Assumindo que `Foto_pet` seja um PNG e `$row` uma linha retornada pela consulta:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Foto_pet'] ).'"/>';
```

Lembrando que a melhor e mais eficiente maneira de armazenar e recuperar fotos é via sistema operacional deixando apenas o caminho registrado no banco de dados.

Referencias:

- [Manual PHP | função base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php)
- [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/137387)